# ERlang list Ctrl changing colors

Tags: list, colors, erlang

Hi I am trying to change an individual item in a listCtrl in erlang.

I initialize listCtrl then I goto set the item as follows:

```
wxListCtrl:setItem(ListCtrl, Row, 1, io_lib:format("~.2f",[VolumeB + 0.00 ])),
    wxListCtrl:setItemBackgroundColour(ListCtrl, 1, ?wxRED),
```

Problem is the background color of the entire row is red,  I only want one column in one row to change, not the entire row.

This is a tough one, at least for me, I haven't seen any simple straight forward docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wx is an Erlang port/wrapper of wxWidgets, so if you're having trouble with things like wxListCtrl:SetItemBackgroundColour(), you'll probably have more luck with the wxWidgets documentation than the (Erlang) wx documentation: [listCtrl documentation at docs.wxwidgets.org](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_list_ctrl.html)

That said, a quick Google suggests that [wxListCtrl doesn't provide a way to specify the background color of a column or a cell](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/9923).